# Google Analytics with SPA (Angular.js)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-analytics

I've built a SPA website using Angular.js.

How can I configure Google Analytics to identify every page change?

Answer (score 4):

When you deal with SPAs you should avoid firing a pageview when the webpage is loaded in the user's browser because in your Google Analytics reports only the first view will be shown (e.g. index.html). As Google suggests, you should use virtual page views. For Angular specifically, you can do that by dropping the pageview tracking code in your `View Router`.

If that sounds too complicated, you can take a look at [Angularlytics](https://github.com/mgonto/angularytics). With a simple configuration and inclusion of the module into your Angular application, all of your views will be tracked automatically.